# Scan an image from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image-scanner

how can i scan an image from a webpage in asp.net.
I need a free control or a code to scan an image from a scanner in 
any user that requests the webpage.
Thank you.

Comment: do you want to scan from a scanner or a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

It is not like you can't do it. But it is not a scalable option in my opinion.

1. You can use ActiveX control - But that won't work in all browsers.
2. You can't use Windows Image Acquisition library directly from ASP.NET on the client side, since the code would run at the server.

Why not simply have the image uploaded?